# How can I filter json using lodash.js or underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying banging my head to filter json written below to get desired result.

```
[{
        "Key": "EShSOKthupE=",
        "ImageUrl": "path",
        "Title": "ABC", 
        "CityId": 16, 
        "TimezoneShortName": "PYT",
        "UtcHrsDiff": 8.5,
        "PlaceKey": "QIZHdWOa77o=",
        "PlaceName": "Shymala Hills Slums",
        "Lat": 23.2424856,
        "Long": 77.39488289999997,
        "ActivityList": [ "Test Activity" ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "NXLQpZAZT4M=",
        "ImageUrl": "",
        "Title": "ASAS",  
        "CityId": 17, 
        "TimezoneShortName": "AEST",
        "UtcHrsDiff": 10,
        "PlaceKey": "o4fAkahBzYY=",
        "PlaceName": "ASAS",
        "Lat": 12.9856503,
        "Long": 77.60569269999996,
        "ActivityList": [ "Adventure Sport" ]
      }]
```

Now I want to get json like this from above json using lodash or undescore js.

```
[{
    "PlaceKey": "QIZHdWOa77o=",
    "PlaceName": "ABC",
    "Lat": 23.2424856,
    "Long": 77.39488289999997
  },
  {
    "PlaceKey": "o4fAkahBzYY=",
    "PlaceName": "ASAS",
    "Lat": 12.9856503,
    "Long": 77.60569269999996,
  }]
```

Any help I can get on this?

Comment: I have used filter _.filter to get this but donno exaclty how to get the result I have mentioned.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is marked as negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this simply in Javascript, **without the need of any external library** like :

```
filteredArray=arr.map(function(item){
  return {
    "PlaceKey": item.PlaceKey,
    "PlaceName": item.PlaceName,
    "Lat": item.Lat,
    "Long": item.Long,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 9):

Using lodash:

```
_.map(yourArray, (el => _.pick(el, ['PlaceKey', 'PlaceName', 'Lat', 'Long'])))
```

Answer (score 3):

use `_.map` function

```
var finalArray = _.map(your_arr, function(obj) {
    return {
    "PlaceKey": obj.PlaceKey,
    "PlaceName": obj.PlaceName,
    "Lat": obj.Lat,
    "Long": obj.Long,
  }
});
```

or just use the arrays `map` function:

```
var finalArray = your_arr.map(function(obj) {
   return {
     "PlaceKey": obj.PlaceKey,
     "PlaceName": obj.PlaceName,
     "Lat": obj.Lat,
     "Long": obj.Long,
   }
});
```

Comment: I was trying to use the same `.filter`. was that wrong/lengthy?

Comment: The map method is used to convert each item of an array, while the filter method is used to select certain items of an array. in this case it does not matter

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation.but by your logic `.filter`  can be used to select some properties on each object? isn't it? so cant we select complete `return el.PlaceKey && el.PlaceName`

Comment: yeah but in this case, we have to loop through all object and access some properties of that object .